# Showing reminder depends on conditions cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

I am developing a Cordova application using Framework7.

This application lets user input a specific time (e.g. 17:00).
It also has a button for user to click.

When user clicks the button, it will store a value in local storage to indicate that user has clicked the button.

Everyday at specified time it will check in local storage whether user has clicked the button or not.

If user hasn't clicked the button the application will show a reminder asking him or her to click the button.

After researching I intend to use cordova-plugin-local-notifications

[cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

But the problem is even though I can schedule cordova-plugin-local-notification to show a reminder at specified time, I can't use it to access local storage to check if user has clicked button or not.

And I also can't cancel a scheduled reminder either.

Is there any alternative plugin to address my problem?